# How to change sqoop metastore?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, sqoop, sqoop2

I am using sqoop 1.4.2 version.
I am trying to change the sqoop metastore from default hsqldb to mysql.

I have configured following properties in sqoop-site.xml file.

```
    <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.enable.autoconnect</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>If true, Sqoop will connect to a local metastore
      for job management when no other metastore arguments are
      provided.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.url</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://ip:3206/sqoop?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.username</name>
    <value>userName</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>sqoop.metastore.client.autoconnect.password</name>
    <value>password</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

When I try to create a sqoop jobs with meta-connect url it fails to connect to configured mysql db.

```
sqoop job --create --meta-connect {mysql_jdbc_url} sqoop job defination
```

it is throwing following exception.

```
    14/06/06 15:04:54 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4.2.0.6.1-101
14/06/06 15:04:55 WARN hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Could not interpret as a number: null
14/06/06 15:04:55 ERROR hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: Can not interpret metadata schema
14/06/06 15:04:55 ERROR hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: The metadata schema version is null
14/06/06 15:04:55 ERROR hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: The highest version supported is 0
14/06/06 15:04:55 ERROR hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage: To use this version of Sqoop, you must downgrade your metadata schema.
14/06/06 15:04:55 ERROR tool.JobTool: I/O error performing job operation: java.io.IOException: Invalid metadata version.
        at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.init(HsqldbJobStorage.java:202)
        at org.apache.sqoop.metastore.hsqldb.HsqldbJobStorage.open(HsqldbJobStorage.java:161)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.JobTool.run(JobTool.java:274)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:222)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:231)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:240)
```

Does sqoop 1.4.2 supports metastore other than hsql db?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is Yes, in my case I am using PostgreSQL.  I ran into this recently and I am using Version 1.4.4.  I am not sure if what I did is the recommended way, but it works.  Here are the steps I followed

1. In sqoop-site.xml I configured it with, the connect string to my database, username and password.
2. Created the following object in the database, as Sqoop was failing at it.

   `CREATE TABLE SQOOP_ROOT (
       version INT, 
       propname VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
       propval VARCHAR(256),
       CONSTRAINT SQOOP_ROOT_unq UNIQUE (version, propname)
   );`
3. Inserted the following row (This seems to be the reason your script is failing)

   `INSERT INTO 
       SQOOP_ROOT 
   VALUES(
       NULL,
       'sqoop.hsqldb.job.storage.version',
       '0'
   );`

I think the correct way might be is to download the source, and extend 
`org.apache.sqoop.metastore.JobStorage` with you DB implementation.

Comment: It does not work for mysql. sqoop failed to update last value when do increment import.

Comment: Worked for me. Please note that both database and table should be granted for the configured user. See also http://rustymartin-solutions.blogspot.it/2015/04/sqoop-mysql-metastore-configuration-on.html for client configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Sqoop metastore does not support any other database other hsqldb. Number 2 points of notes on the link.
[cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh4/latest/CDH4-Requirements-and-Supported-Versions/cdhrsv_topic_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Public service announcement: Sqoop Metastore on other DBs may fail**

We have been able to get PostgreSQL and MySQL working as targets for the Sqoop Metastore on Sqoop 1, replacing the HyperSQL database.  There's a little setup and seeding of the database needed, but from then on, it seemed fine.

**However**, we are seeing cases when we are running many sqoop jobs, updating the metastore concurrently -- sqoop 1.4.6 has no code to trap and handle cases where metastore updates for incremental updates fail due to concurrency issues.  In particular, Sqoop _will complete it's import successfully but not update the metastore with the most recently imported values.  This will cause the **next incremental run will import duplicate data**.  Sqoop will return a non-zero return code, but data in either Hadoop or the metastore need to be synced afterward in order for data to be correct.

We're not sure there is a solution, but this is an expansion of @SandeerKumar's answer.  This may be an issue with HyperSQL as well, but it would be much less likely because HSQL is in memory, so faster.