# can we use any other metastore other than the default HSQLDB in sqoop 1.4.2?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

can we use any other metastore(like MYSQL) other than the default HSQLDB in sqoop 1.4.2 .If yes,the HOW?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is similar to the answer for these question [How to change sqoop metastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24078668/how-to-change-sqoop-metastore)
Hope these will solve your problem.